# esptool.py fail to install on mac

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `esptool.py` to flash ESP32. Since I use Arduino IDE I assume it is installed and work correctly. But since I need to work using command line I encounter problems regarding `python2.7` which send an end of life messages, and `python3.8`, both installed on my mac.

I followed [esptool github pages](https://github.com/espressif/esptool#usage), for example:

```
guydvir@Guy-MacBookPro ~ % pip install esptool
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: esptool in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial>=3.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from esptool) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: ecdsa>=0.16.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from esptool) (0.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.1.4 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from esptool) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: reedsolo<=1.5.4,>=1.5.3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from esptool) (1.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: bitstring>=3.1.6 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from esptool) (3.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from ecdsa>=0.16.0->esptool) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography>=2.1.4->esptool) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography>=2.1.4->esptool) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography>=2.1.4->esptool) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography>=2.1.4->esptool) (1.0.22)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.1.4->esptool) (2.19)
guydvir@Guy-MacBookPro ~ %
```

I mostly get this warning regarding v2.7.
By the way, when using a `venv` problem was solved, but I rather know what is wrong.

Guy

Comment: Is the end of life message the only problem?

Comment: Typing ‘esptool’ yields an error

Comment: Since you have two Python versions, you should select the right pip when installing something - aka check/verify first paths with ```which pip``` and ```pip --version```, and for Python very 3.x use ```pip3 install ...``` or ```python3 bla...``` to start Python 3x. Take care the command suggested on esp githhub pages is ```esptool.py rest-of-command```. You may need to ```chmod +x esptool.py``` to allow it to be started simply ```esptool```.

Comment: re "Typing ‘esptool’ yields an error " what is the exact error?

Comment: The same with me: Mac OS M1 Monterey 12.4  can't install esptool (with python 3.10)